# Possible to use a CursorAdapter in conjunction with a Static string array?

Tags: android, mysql, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

Dislaimer: I'm not asking for someone to do the work for me, just asking for the best way to go about accomplishing this.

I need to present two numeric values for a list of 12 items on a page.   The page looks like this (still working on the layout)
[image: layout]

I originally constructed this from a scroll view, plus relative layouts for each row.   I'm getting a warning from Eclipse that the view now has over 80 views, and will cause performance problems, so I'd like to do this from a cursor adapter, and a single list row layout.

The problem is, If i use a cursor adapter on the database table containing the recorded items I want to pull, I'm only going to get a list of items that the user has already logged for a list.   I'm wondering if it's possible to have all the items show (provided either from a string array, or another database table that contains all the moves), then pull the numbers from the database. (the buttons at the bottom control how far to pull data from)

I was thinking I might be able to use a custom cursor adapter, or override the binding on the cursor adapter, but if anyone knows a way to accomplish this, I'm all ears!

I have a table that contains all the moves, such as:

```
ID    moveName
----------------
1     Takedown
2     Sweep
3     Reversal
```

etc

I want this entire table to populate the listview (so I get 12 rows)

Then have it pull the #'s from another table:

```
SELECT COUNT(moves) FROM movesHistory WHERE moveName = <name> AND date = NOW - <button pressed>
```

that's not proper SQL syntax clearly, just demonstrating what I'd use.  I'm going to wrap it in a function so I can just pass in the month to find when the user presses a button at the bottom.

I would use something similar to this:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get a cursor with all people
   Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT ... FROM " + TableName , null);
    startManagingCursor(c);

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            // Use a template that displays a text view
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            // Give the cursor to the list adatper
            c,
            // Map the NAME column in the people database to...
            new String[] {Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},
            // The "text1" view defined in the XML template
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**Edit 12/14/12:**

After reading another SO link, This might be easily accomplished with a Join of some sorts.   I'm trying to figure out now if it's possible to Select all records from the BJJ names table, then select the sum of each move type from the other table.

Is it possible to select all rows from this table:
[image: bjj moves]

and then the total number of moves by and against from this table:
[image: bjj history]

To make something like this:

```
Name          Taps   Tapped
Takedown       0       0 
sweep          0       0
reversal       1       0
choke          2       1
arm lock       0       0
leg lock       0       1
guard pass     0       0
guard pull     0       1
back           0       0
sweep          1       0
throw          1       0
guard          1       0
```

If the users name is in the Against column, it would count as Tapped, if the users name was in the "By" Column, the move would count as "Taps"   I'm reading about Joins right now, but nesting selects, counts, etc is a little confusing to me right now as I'm limited to pretty much basic Select/Insert/Update/ commands.

I found the following page: http://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/sum-and-count-using-variable.php

that lists using count and sum in a join, but I get an error when I try the following:
[image: error]

**EDIT #3**

**SUCCESS!**

Here is the SQL Query:

```
SELECT taps1.moveName, IFNULL( taps1.taps, 0 ) AS Taps  , IFNULL( tapped1.tapped, 0 ) AS Tapped 
FROM (

  SELECT bj.moveName, bh.taps
  FROM BJJ_moves bj
  LEFT JOIN (

    SELECT Move, SUM( MoveCount ) AS taps
    FROM BJJ
    WHERE MoveBy = '<NAME>'
    GROUP BY Move
  )bh ON bh.Move = bj.moveName
)taps1
LEFT JOIN (

  SELECT Move, SUM( MoveCount ) AS tapped
  FROM BJJ
  WHERE AGAINST = '<NAME>'
  GROUP BY Move
)tapped1 ON tapped1.Move = taps1.MoveName
```

And here is the resulting table it produces (except I've modified it to turn NULL to 0, and change the column names):
[image: result table]

I just now need to put this query into a cursor and it'll feed the listview.

Comment: (Ju-Jitsu and Android... stranger things have happened. :) I'm not certain what "the problem" is, I didn't follow that paragraph. Are you concerned with keeping the data in the ListView current?

Comment: The form has two functions.  First, at the bottom, the users can see how many moves they've either done against someone or had done to them over specific periods.  Upon pressing the button, the list would update.   Second function is that if they "tap" the row, they can log a new record against/to them.

Comment: Ok, I agree using a ListView with a custom CursorAdapter is the most efficient route especially since you seem to have the database set up already. Do you need help overriding `bindView()`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm all for doing some things "the fancy way", but I've found if you're just dealing with text and static data (and not a ton of it), you can safely ignore the "warning from Eclipse that the view now has over 80 views".

You will certainly run into problems loading 1000's of items into a view, which is why you would want to use a list view.  But if you are at 100 or so, or even a few hundred, I think most modern devices can keep up just fine from what I've experienced.

That being said, if your app will expand or become much more dynamic or graphically intense, then certainly heed that warning.  Yes you can certainly pull this data from a database, I recommend using a ListView with CursorLoader and of course the embedded android sql lite database engine.  There are loads of great tutorials out there for this.

Comment: Thanks.   We're not expecting more than 12 rows currently, and when running on my HTC One X, there certainly are no visible performance impacts from creating each row by hand (except that to change the row layout I have to tweak 12 rows manually, and the resulting XML is over 900 lines (even with styles)

I was thinking of using a cursorloader though to simplify things, just wondering if it's possible to pull from one table, while grabbing data from another table.   I suppose I could do something like a cursorloader, then override the viewbinder to grab data from the other table...

Comment: @EvanR. Maintaining a file 900 lines long could be a compelling  reason to use listview and at least an array if not sql.  On the other hand going back to what I said earlier, you can safley make each XML element a 1 line statement to reduce complexity (actually whole file can be one line, but don't recommended).

Comment: Things grow out of hand quickly even if you dont expect them to so i like to be prepared for BIG even if they never will be

Answer (score 0):

So the final result I think is going to be a cursoradapter (later a cursor loader w/ compatibility library, but I need to read about them first) with the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT taps1.moveName AS move, IFNULL(taps1.taps, 0) AS taps, IFNULL(tapped1.tapped,0) AS tapped
FROM (
  SELECT bj.moveName, bh.taps
  FROM BJJ_moves bj
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Move, SUM( MoveCount) AS taps
    FROM BJJ
    WHERE MoveBy = 'Evan Richardson'
    AND Date > DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL <X> MONTH)
    GROUP BY Move
  )bh ON bh.Move=bj.moveName
)taps1
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT Move, SUM(MoveCount) AS tapped
   FROM BJJ
   WHERE Against = 'Evan Richardson'
   AND Date > DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL <X> MONTH)
   GROUP BY Move
)tapped1 ON tapped1.Move = taps1.MoveName
```

This gives me a table with the 3 columns I need for the listview, that can then be filled into a list with the adapter.  Replace "X" with a variable value based on the button pressed.

Thanks all!